# Send object data in a sorted order fetched through axios in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, axios

I am using axios to fetch data and send it using express but i want to send the data which is in sorted order according to one of its values. How can I sort this response.data.

```
app.get("/country", (req, res) => {
  const url = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries`;
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.data;
      res.render("country", { data: data });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
    })
    .finally(function () {});
});
```

Comment: please add an example of your response data received.

Comment: please share what you specifically have tried to sort the data. Which methods have you specifically tried? I don't see anything in your code attempting to do any sorting.

Comment: Assume data is in json format and i want to sort it using the property "cases"
`[
{
updated: 1595755847576,
country: "USA",
countryInfo: {
_id: 840,
iso2: "US",
iso3: "USA",
lat: 38,
long: -97,
flag: "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/us.png"
},
cases: 4315709,

},
{
updated: 1595755847578,
country: "India",
countryInfo: {
_id: 356,
iso2: "IN",
iso3: "IND",
lat: 20,
long: 77,
flag: "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/in.png"
},
cases: 415709,
}
]
`

Answer (score 0):

Given your data is an unsorted array of object, you can use the sort method of Array type to sort your object ([sort documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort))

example:

```js
const data = [ { updated: 1595755847576, country: "USA", countryInfo: { _id: 840, iso2: "US", iso3: "USA", lat: 38, long: -97, flag: "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/us.png" }, cases: 4315709,  }, { updated: 1595755847578, country: "India", countryInfo: { _id: 356, iso2: "IN", iso3: "IND", lat: 20, long: 77, flag: "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/in.png" }, cases: 415709, } ];
const result = data.sort((elem1, elem2) => elem1.cases - elem2.cases )

console.log(result)
```